# Spring Boot MVC app: How to redirect without changing the URL

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc

For example I am using the following to redirect requests -

```
   @GetMapping(value="/Redirect")
ResponseEntity<Void> redirect(){
    return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.FOUND)
            .location(URI.create("https://google.com"))
            .build();
}
```

And it works fine but, as expected it shows google.com as the URL. How can I redirect while showing the previous page's url?

Comment: I'd say you can't do that just in Spring

Comment: In your example, you redirect to an external URL (I just go ahead and assume you are not asking this for the Spring Boot app that is google.com ;-) ). As SirKometa says, this is impossible inside one (any) application. You might be interested in the Spring functionality that is called "forwarding". It is similar to redirects but does everything server side and thus keeps the URL the same. See here for an explanation: https://www.baeldung.com/spring-redirect-and-forward#forward-with-the-prefix-forward